# How do I use the annotation and micro in the mod of the test scope?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

The structure of my code as below.

[image]

I ran 'cargo run' and it works. But when I ran 'cargo test', I got the errors as below. Could you please tell me why and how can I fix them?

> error: cannot find attribute `get` in this scope
>
> error: cannot find macro `routes` in this scope

src/main.rs

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

mod common;

fn main() {
    common::run();
}
```

src/common.rs

```
#[get("/hello")]
pub fn hello() -> &'static str {
    "hello"
}

pub fn run() {
    rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![hello]).launch();
}
```

---

tests/development.rs

```
#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene, decl_macro)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

#[cfg(test)]
mod common;

#[test]
fn test_development_config() {
    common::run();
}
```

tests/common.rs

```
use rocket::http::Status;
use rocket::local::Client;

#[get("/check_config")]
fn check_config() -> &'static str {
    "hello"
}

pub fn run() {
    let rocket = rocket::ignite().mount("/", routes![check_config]);

    let client = Client::new(rocket).unwrap();
    let response = client.get("/hello").dispatch();
    assert_eq!(response.status(), Status::Ok);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `.rs` file in the `tests/` folder is separately compiled and executed as a test. So `development.rs` is compiled, "includes" `common.rs` and it works. But then `common.rs` is compiled individually and it fails because there is no `#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;` anywhere.

One solution would be to put your `common.rs` into `tests/common/mod.rs`. Files in sub-directories of `tests` are not automatically compiled as test.